# Convertir html a pdf con estilos utilizando mpdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, mpdf

Hola estoy tratando de crear un pdf mediante un boton, tengo un archivo txt con codigo html el cual deseo pasar a pdf

el codigo php es:

```
echo    '<div class="row cnt-desing-credencial" id="cnt-desing-credencial">
            <div class="col-12 title">
                <h3 class="" style="background-color:teal; color:white; border-radius:5px; padding:3px; letter-spacing:2px; font-family:helvetica; text-align:center;"> 
                    <SMALL style="color:white;">TITULO</SMALL>
                </h3>
            </div>';
echo $html; //contenido del archivo previamente leído y extraído
echo    '</div>';

//Estoy utilizando yii2
echo Html::beginForm(Url::toRoute("trabajadores/fg"),"POST",['class' => 'form-control2']).
    '<input type="hidden" id="html" name="html" value="">'.
    '<button class="btnModal btnSave" id="btnImprimirPdf" type="submit" class="btn-sm" onclick="e()">Guardar</button>'. // e()
Html::endForm();
```

Donde la variable $html es el contenido del archivo txt el cual si se visualiza en mi pagina perfectamente incluyendo con los estilos.

En el botón, mediante el evento onclick obtengo la función e() de javascript la cual obtiene todo el codigo html que esta adentro de la etiqueta

```
<div class="row cnt-desing-credencial" id="cnt-desing-credencial">
```

para asignarlo a

```
<input type="hidden" id="html" name="html" value="">
```

el código de JavaScript que también se encuentra en el mismo archivo php es:

```
<script>
    function e(){
        let cod = document.getElementById("cnt-desing-credencial").innerHTML;
      
        let txt = document.getElementById("html");
        txt.setAttribute("value",cod);

        //En la consola se muestraperfectamente el contenido
        console.log("VAL: " + txt.value);
    }
</script>
```

Mientras que en el controlador, recibo el valor del input tipo hidden y es hay donde pretendo imprimir el pdf

```
function actionFg(){
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

    $htmlGet = Html::encode($_POST["html"]);
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $css = file_get_contents('../web/css/credenciales.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($css, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlGet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
    $mpdf->Output('ok.pdf','D');
    exit;
```

Cabe aclarar que el pdf si lo imprime pero solo aparece el titulo de la etiquete h3.

Realmente no se por que pasa eso, el contenido del html el controlador lo recibe correctamente, cabe aclarar que el html contiene estilos como bordes, colores de fondo e imágenes de fondo no se si las imagenes son lo que cause esto.

Si me pudieran ayudar por favor o alguna otra librería que se pueda implementar con yii2 y que acepte este tipo de estilos

Comment: Hola, ¿cuál es el problema que estás teniendo con exactitud?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, estoy creando un "diseñador de credenciales" donde puedo arrastrar y soltar objetos, entre otras cosas, ese codigo html lo guardo en un txt, ya que tengo que guardar el diseño, cuando lo quiero convertir en pdf en otra vista obtengo el contenido del txt en una variable y la imprimo para que el diseño se visualice y se visualiza perfectamente a como lo diseñe previamente, el punto es que al tratar de convertir a pdf esa misma variable la paso a la libreria para que convierta su contenido a pdf lo cual no se vizualiza nada en el pdf